# Copy output without output buffering

Tags: php, console

I have a PHP script that write into consol some logs,erros etc.

I want to save all this information into a variable for sending an email at the end of its execution.

I know i can use obstart and co for doing that but I also want that during its execution that the logs appear in **real time**. So I don't think the output buffering is the solution for my problem but I don't see another solution.

Is there a way for doing that please ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to come up with some kind of custom logger that apart from outputing messages to console will also send an email on script shutdown. Something like this:

```
interface MailerInterface {
    function send($recipient, $title, $body);
}

interface LoggerInterface {
    function log($message);
}

class ConsoleLoggerWithMailer implements LoggerInterface {

    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    private $messages = array();

    /**
     * @var MailerInterface
     */
    private $mailer;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $recipient;

    public function __construct() {
        register_shutdown_function(array($this, 'sendMessages'));
    }

    /**
     * @param MailerInterface $mailer
     * @param string $recipient
     */
    public function setMailer(MailerInterface $mailer, $recipient) {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->recipient = $recipient;
    }

    /**
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getMessages() {
        return $this->messages;
    }

    public function log($message) {
        $this->messages[] = $message;

        printf("%s\n", $message);
    }

    public function sendMessages() {
        if ($this->mailer === null || count($this->messages) === 0)
            return;

        $this->mailer->send($this->recipient, 'log', implode("\n", $this->messages));
    }
}
```

Usage example assuming you also created some Mailer class implementing MailerInterface:

```
$mailer = new Mailer();
$logger = new ConsoleLoggerWithMailer();
$logger->setMailer($mailer, "webmaster@example.com");

$logger->log("Starting...");
$logger->log("Doing...");
$logger->log("End");
```

Comment: I will try a solution like that. Thanks for register_shutdown_function(), I didn't know but very usefull.